# glibc version used while building .a file

Tags: glibc, unix-ar

Is there a way to find out from .a file what version of glibc is expected or was used when building the .a?

Comment: I don't see why there would be.

Comment: Because .a is an unlinked file. It can theoretically be linked to different versions of glibc, assuming what's in the .h files doesn't change. See bmargulies's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a meaningful question about an ar file or a .o file. All they record is naked symbol names. When you make a shared object or an executable, the linker gives you symbols references like `time@@GLIBC_2.2.5` for the undefined symbols.